# Using Vue, what is the best way to use a Pagination component in multiple parent components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a Vue Pagination component which will be used by multiple areas to enable pagination for the different content tables. From the that tables, I send the following `props` to the Pagination component `offset`, `limit`, `total` and `parent_name`.

```html
<pagination v-bind:offset="offset" v-bind:limit="limit" v-bind:total="total" pagination_object="parent_object_name"></pagination>
```

The Pagination component has a Next and Previous button which are enabled/disabled appropriately based on the props coming in. I’m not sure how better to handle the click events for Next and Previous events. I need to send these events back to the calling parent component.

Currently I’m using an event bus to send the click events and passing in the parent object name to distinguish which parent is being used.

```js
methods: {
    previous() {
        event_bus.$emit('pagination_previous', this.pagination_object);
    },
    next() {
        event_bus.$emit('pagination_next', this.pagination_object);
    }
}
```

Then in the parent objects, I listen for these events and see if the parent object name matches.

```js
created() {
    event_bus.$on('pagination_previous', pagination_object => {
        if (pagination_object === 'my_name') {
            // Perform the action
        }
    }),

    event_bus.$on('pagination_next', pagination_object => {
        if (pagination_object === 'my_name') {
            // Perform the action
        }
    });
}
```

Is there better way to send the click events back to the calling parent? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use `this.$emit("pagination_next",yourobject)` it's easier than `eventBus`

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Is there a more elegant way to know which parent is using the pagination component without having to use a `parent_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the child component try to use `this.$emit(...)` function to send an event and other wished parameters to the parent:

```
  methods: {
      previous() {
      this.$emit('pagination_previous', this.pagination_object);
      },
      next() {
        this.$emit('pagination_next', this.pagination_object);
      }
   }
```

in the parent component call the child component as follow  by adding `pagination_previous` and `pagination_next` events without needing to `parent_object_name` property :

```
<pagination v-bind:offset="offset" v-bind:limit="limit" v-bind:total="total"  v-on:pagination_previous="page_prev" v-on:pagination_next="page_next"></pagination>
```

You don't need the to put code into the `created` hook, but you have to add `page_prev` `page_next` to your methods object as follow :

```
  methods:{
     page_prev(pagination_object){
      //todo
    },
    page_next(pagination_object){
      //todo
    }
  ...
 }
```